# prove or give a counter-example

Tags: calculus, proof-writing, proof-verification

I think I have solved it (please check) but I would like to see and (re)-learn how one writes a proper proof (including the mathematical signs) and little things (I might have missed), maybe even more elegant proofs

Problem: Let $I$ be an open interval, and $f:I\rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be continuosly differentiable on $I$. Suppose $a\in I$ and there is an open interval $X \subset I$ containing $a$, an open interval $Y\subset\mathbf{R}$ containing $f(X)$, and a unique function $g:Y\rightarrow X$, such that $g(f(x))=x  \qquad \forall x \in X $. Then $f'(a)\neq0$.

Here is how I proceeded:

***Proof by contradiction***:-

Suppose $f'(a)=0 $.
Since $I$ is an open interval, $\exists \delta>0$ s.t. $f(a)=f(a+\delta)$=y (say), where $a + \delta \in X$

Now, $y\in Y$

$g(y)=g(f(a))=a$

Also, $g(y)=g(f(a+\delta))=a+\delta$

However this contradicts the definition of a function ($g$ in this case), which cannot be one to many.

Hence our initial supposition is incorrect.

Therefore $f'(a)\neq0$

PS:But notice that I haven't used (?) the fact that Y is an open interval...

Comment: To be honest, non of this makes sense. Where do you use that $f'(a)=0$? What exactly is the claimed contradiction?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Thanks very much for the constructive criticism. I used it wrongly as pointed out by others (see when I introduced $y$). Given that $g$ turns out to be one-to-many, it cannot be a function and hence the initial supposition of zero derivative was incorrect---that's what I had in mind

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Hope it is clear? How would have you written a proof by contradiction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you need to assume $g$ is continuously differentiable also. Then, if $f'(a) = 0$ and if $g(f(x)) = x$, then by the chain rule, $g'(f(x))f'(x) = 1$, i.e. $g'(f(a)) = \dfrac{1}{f'(a)}$...

Comment: thanks very much for the kind explanation. Just a small clarification. If my memory serves right, one cannot always equate the derivatives on either side of an equation...or something like that? Can you explain ...it was about some kind of identity vs equation kind of thing? (I do tend to see it's ok in your answer since we have 2 functions of same variable on either side of the equal sign)

Comment: You may be thinking of: If two functions are equal, you have to take the derivatives *before* you evaluate (i.e. set $x = a$). But if $f$ and $g$ are both continuously differentiable on $X$ and $Y \supset f(X)$ respectively, then $f(g(x))$ is continuously differentiable on $X$. Further, $h(x) = x$ is continuously differentiable, so if $f(g(x)) = h(x)$ for all $x \in X$, their derivatives must be equal as well.

Comment: Many thanks yet again. So basically you mean my proof by contradiction is valid only if $g$ is given as continuously differentiable, right?

Comment: Also, in the comment, you mean $g(f(x))$ being continuously differentiable, right? And one final thing (if you don't mind:-)):"If two functions are equal, you have to take the derivatives before you evaluate (i.e. set x=a)", I guess by this you mean that if you do it the other way, it would always hold good since the derivatives would be 0 (constant)

Comment: Your proof still doesn't quite work because of the issues discussed above (you can't assume $f(a) = f(a + \delta)$. But yes, the statement of the proof is only true if $g$ is cont. diff. (and then you can follow my basic outline above for a valid proof by contradiction). Yes, you are right about my error. Sorry for that. Finally, yes, that is exactly the right interpretation: if you evaluate first, then you get zero on both sides.

Comment: Many thanks for your clear explanations and patience in my queries. Cheers!

Comment: Great! You're very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let I=X=Y=]-1, 1[. Let f(x)=x^3, g(y)=third root of y. Let a=0. There's your counterexample. But maybe you meant g had to be continuously differentiable, too?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It makes me wonder about 2 things though: What is then wrong with my proof? Also, what does it have to do with g being continuosly differentiable? Many thanks again

Comment: Well, the first flaw in your proof is that there is no reason ∃δ>0 s.t. f(a)=f(a+δ) should be true - in the counterexample you will notice that f is strictly increasing.

Comment: i.e. a function having $f'(a) = 0$ doesn't imply that it is locally constant (as you seem to suggest when you say $f(a) = f(a + \delta) = y$.)

Comment: But f′(a)=0 does imply g can't have a finite derivative at f(a).

Comment: @BaronVT: Thanks guys, I understood the flaw on strictly increasing function, but to understand further what's happening, don't you agree that I just used the definition of the derivative which is lim delta->0  $\frac{f(a+\delta)-f(a)}{\delta}$. Now where's the mistake here?

Comment: If $f'(a) = 0$, then the *limit* you have written is equal to $0$, which is different than saying there is a $\delta > 0$ so that $f(a + \delta) - f(a) = 0$.

Comment: @BaronVT: Thanks very much indeed, very clear now. But I am still having trouble visualizing something to be strictly increasing despite the fact that it's derivative is zero (though hazily I could agree, but still something disturbs me). Intuitively derivative=0 => rate of change =0. Suppose at an infinitesimal distance the value of function is larger (increasing function), doesn't it imply that rate of change is not zero? (PS I well understand the counter-example provided, but I know there is something in my understanding that is not quite right)

Comment: Think again about $x^3$. The function is strictly increasing, with $f'(0) = 0$, but there is no other **non-zero** $x$ so that $f(x) = f(0)$.

Comment: @BaronVT: Yep, got it now. Very glad!